# Split a large text file to small ones based on location

Tags: python, jython-2.7

Suppose I have a big file as file.txt and it has data of around 300,000. I want to split it based on certain key location. See file.txt below:

```
Line 1: U0001;POUNDS;**CAN**;1234
Line 2: U0001;POUNDS;**USA**;1234
Line 3: U0001;POUNDS;**CAN**;1234
Line 100000; U0001;POUNDS;**CAN**;1234
```

The locations are limited to 10-15 different nation. And I need to separate each record of a particular country in one particular file. How to do this task in Python

Thanks for help

Comment: is all the country code just three characters and followed by4 digits ?

Comment: No, it is of Variable length.

Comment: have you try reading files by lines and doing for loop to check if three characters in that line, if its write to text file you want?

Comment: Are you trying to end up with a file for each country or a single file sorted by country?

Comment: Separate file for each country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will run with very low memory overhead as it writes each line as it reads it.

Algorithm:

- open input file
- read a line from input file
- get country from line
- if new country then open file for country
- write the line to country's file
- loop if more lines
- close files

Code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as infile:
    try:
        outfiles = {}
        for line in infile:
            country = line.split(';')[2].strip('*')
            if country not in outfiles:
                outfiles[country] = open(country + '.txt', 'w')
            outfiles[country].write(line)
    finally:
        for outfile in outfiles.values():
            outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
text = [x.strip() for x in content] 

x = [i.split(";") for i in text]
x.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
from itertools import groupby
from operator get itemgetter
y = groupby(x, itemgetter(2))
res = [(i[0],[j for j in i[1]]) for i in y]
for country in res:
     with open(country[0]+".txt","w") as writeFile:
             writeFile.writelines("%s\n" % ';'.join(l) for l in country[1])
```

will group by your item!
Hope it helps!

Comment: What is `text` here?

Comment: `groupby` only groups consecutive objects.  for example, try `groupby([1,1, 2, 2, 1, 1])`  You'll get back something like `[(1, (1, 1)), (2, (2, 2)), (1, (1, 1))]`.  But that means that you have two groups for the same "key" (in this case `1`)

Comment: @user2350068 did that answer your question?

Comment: There's no reason to read the whole file into memory. The splitting can be done on the fly. See my answer for how.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like what you have is a `csv` file.  `csv` stands for comma-separated values, but any file that uses a different delimiter (in this case a semicolon `;`) can be treated like a `csv` file.

We'll use the python module [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read the file in, and then write a file for each country

```
import csv 
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for line in r:
        d[l[2]].append(l)

for country in d:
    with open('{}.txt'.format(country), 'wb') as outfile:
        w = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=';')
        for line in d[country]:
            w.writerow(line)
```

Comment: There's no reason to read the whole file into memory.  The splitting can be done on the fly.  See my answer for how.  (My answer can be modified to use csv and the logic would be the same.)

Answer (score -1):

```
# the formatting-function for the filename used for saving
outputFileName = "{}.txt".format
# alternative:
##import time
##outputFileName = lambda loc: "{}_{}.txt".format(loc, time.asciitime())

#make a dictionary indexed by location, the contained item is new content of the file for the location
sortedByLocation = {}
f = open("file.txt", "r")

#iterate each line and look at the column for the location
for l in f.readlines():
    line = l.split(';')
    #the third field (indices begin with 0) is the location-abbreviation
    # make the string lower, cause on some filesystems the file with upper chars gets overwritten with only the elements with lower characters, while python differs between the upper and lower
    location = line[2].lower().strip()
    #get previous lines of the location and store it back
    tmp = sortedByLocation.get(location, "")
    sortedByLocation[location]=tmp+l.strip()+'\n'

f.close()

#save file for each location
for location, text in sortedByLocation.items():
    with open(outputFileName(location) as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Comment: This is bad.  Building output by continually adding lines to a string is horribly inefficient.  Each line is about 25 characters.  The first time you do `tmp+l.strip()+'\n'` you'll be creating a string of 25 characters.  On the next iteration you'll copy that 25 character string into a new string and add 25 more.  An on the next you'll copy 50 and add 25.  Then copy 75 and add 25.  So by 4 iterations you will have copied 150 characters to create a 100 character string.  If 10% of the 300k lines belong to 1 file you will have copied over 11 billion characters to create 750k characters.